# discord.py выдача ролей

Tags: python, api, discord.py

написал команду mute, а она не работает(

вот код:

```
@s.bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member, mute_minute, *, reason):
    for role in s.role_for_mute:
        if role in [r.id for r in ctx.author.roles]:
            if member == s.bot.user:
                await ctx.channel.send("Нельзя мутить бота!")
                return
            roleM = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, id=656928235866554368)
            print(roleM)
            print(member)
            await member.add_roles(roleM) #эта строчка не выполняется, а за ней и все остальные(либо же она выполняется, но очень долго. Я просто написал: "!mute @name 1 f", и ждал 5м и ничего не произошло)
            # embed = discord.Embed(title="Muted", description=str(member) + " has muted!")
            await ctx.channel.send("Muted")
            return
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@client.command (pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True)
async def mute (ctx,member:discord.Member,time:int,reason):
    channel = client.get_channel (758393130755162123)
    mute = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'mute')
    lol = discord.Embed(title = 'В муте. Говорить не может!' )
    lol.add_field(name = 'Модератор/админ', value = ctx.message.author.mention, inline = False)
    lol.add_field(name = 'Нарушитель', value = member.mention, inline = False)
    lol.add_field(name= 'Причина', value = reason, inline = False)
    lol.add_field (name = 'Время', value = time, inline = False)
    await member.add_roles (mute)
    await channel.send (embed = lol )
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
    await member.remove_roles (mute)
```

Попробуй этот код. И импортируй библиотеку asyncio.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Вот вав полностью рабочий код для команды `mute`:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio, asyncpg
import os

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def mute(self, ctx, who: discord.Member, reason: str = None):
    
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    try:
        
        role = ctx.message.guild.get_role(id_role)#здесь вы указываете роля для `mute`
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    
        if reason is None:
            
            mute = discord.Embed(
                title = f'{who} получил мут',
                timestamp = ctx.message.created_at,
                colour = discord.Color.green()
                ) 
            mute.add_field(
                name = 'Пользователь',
                value = f'{who.mention}'
                )
            mute.add_field(
                name = 'Модератор',
                value = f'{ctx.message.author.mention}'
                )
            mute.add_field(
                name = 'Причина',
                value = 'Не указана'
            )
            
            await ctx.send(embed = mute)
            await who.add_roles(role)
        
        else:
            
            mute = discord.Embed(
                title = f'{who} получил мут',
                timestamp = ctx.message.created_at,
                colour = discord.Color.green()
                ) 
            mute.add_field(
                name = 'Пользователь',
                value = f'{who.mention}'
                )
            mute.add_field(
                name = 'Модератор',
                value = f'{ctx.message.author.mention}'
                )
            mute.add_field(
                name = 'Причина',
                value = f'{reason}'
            )
            
            await ctx.send(embed = mute)
            await who.add_roles(role)
    
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'[{ctx.message.created_at}] [{ctx.message.guild.name}] [{ctx.message.guild.owner}] - [{e}]')

async def cog_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    await ctx.send('Произошла ошибка: {}'.format(str(error)))
    print(f'[{ctx.message.created_at}] [{ctx.message.guild.name}] [{ctx.message.guild.owner}] - [{error}]')
```

Вот еще дам вам кусок кода, который снимет мут после определенного периода времени, но сразу предупреждаю что когда вы перезагружаете бота то таймер сбрасывается на 0, и роль не будет снята с пользователя:

```
   if what == str('m'): минуты
        if time >=1 and time <= 59:
            
            await ctx.send(f'--> {who} получил мут на {time}м. по причине: {reason}')

            await who.add_roles(role)
            await who.move_to(None)
            await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
            await who.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send('Мут забраний')
    
    if what == str('h'):# години
        if time >= 1 and time <= 24:
            await ctx.send(f'--> {who} получил мут на {time}ч. по причине: {reason}')

            await who.add_roles(role)
            await who.move_to(None)
            await asyncio.sleep(time * 3600)
            await who.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send('Мут забраний')
    
    if what == str('d'):# дни
        if time >= 1 and time <= 365:
            await ctx.send(f'--> {who} получил мут на {time}д. по причине: {reason}')

            await who.add_roles(role)
            await who.move_to(None)
            await asyncio.sleep(time * 86400)
            await who.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send('Мут забраний')
    
    if what == str('y'):# роки
        if time >= 1:
            await ctx.send(f'--> {who} получил мут на {time}л. по причине: {reason}')

            await who.add_roles(role)
            await who.move_to(None)
            await asyncio.sleep(time * 31557600)
            await who.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send('Мут забраний')
```

Тогда здесь будет так:

```
async def mute(self, ctx, who: discord.Member, minutes:str, reason: str = None):
```

И использовать:

```
.mute @user#1010 m SPAM
```